# javascript get nested array elements

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

in javascript how do I get individual elements out of this array?

http://pastebin.com/n8yrnCpf

I need to loop through it and format the data

how would I get array[0][1][1], for instance

and perhaps there is some json script for doing it quickly

Comment: Have you actually _tried_ `array[0][1][1]` to get `array[0][1][1]`?

Comment: Json is a data interchange format. You can't script in that.

Comment: If you wrote the code that produces this mess, I highly suggest you to rewrite it and use objects. You can then address the correct data without infinite nested loops.

Comment: If you want to parse JSON into javascript object, look into the `JSON` class. If you need to support old IE, jQuery can help, as well as any decent shim.

Comment: @Masiar not sure how this array could be objectified unless specific indexes hold - oh, wait - the last level should be objectified.

Comment: @JanDvorak that's what I meant, also I don't see the point keeping a 2-dimensional array in this case, so maybe we can objectify the outmost array as well, given meaningful indexes.

Comment: @JanDvorak no, I haven't tried that, I am switching between php and javascript, some of the obvious syntax gets overlooked

Comment: @Masiar the root issue is that I have to create this thing with PHP in an ajax call, if its not valid json then the ajax won't return, if I return it as text, then I won't have objects. So my conclusion is that I need to format the data in javascript after the ajax call returns valid json

Comment: @CQM the `JSON` format is just stringified JavaScript... if you create an object and then call `JSON.stringify(obj);` then what is returned is a JSON object that can be sent as an answer to an AJAX request. On the other side, you just need to do `JSON.parse(answer);` and you will get access to the object again. Hope it helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Json comes from **J** ava **S** cript **O** bject **N** otation. It's a javascript-compatible format, so you can loop through it, and access it as you need. In other words, you *do* can get `array[0][1][1]`.

If what you're asking for is how can you receive a JSON in a string and convert it to an "usable" JavaScript variable, you can do that this way:

```
var json_string = "[[['whatever','and'],['more','whatever']]]"
var parsed_json = JSON.parse (json_string)
console.log (parsed_json[0][0])
```

Or, if you use old browsers (IE7 and so), you can use JQuery and its elder-safe function parseJSON:

```
var json_string = "[[['whatever','and'],['more','whatever']]]"
var parsed_json = $.parseJSON (json_string)
console.log (parsed_json[0][0])
```

Comment: i would not recommend naming a variable "object", otherwise good answer.

Comment: Note that the JSON class is not available in ancient browsers.

Comment: I fixed the data as suggested, just took a little more cognitive effort, thanks all